# How to change Xcode behavior? Change breakpoint setting in Xcode Setting?

Tags: objective-c, xcode7.3, ios9.3

How to change breakpoint setting in Xcode?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

Currently display breakpoint on Xcode :-

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

Now I am showing below screen after debug application:

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and I want to change my breakpoint setting. Please check below screen shot. How can I change setting?

Comment: I don't see any difference in those screenshots, and you have not described what you are trying to accomplish.  Change the breakpoint in what way?

Comment: please check now there is two Images

Comment: Which screenshots?

Comment: got problem if you call below method on terminal :-
defaults delete com.apple.dt.
Xcode work perfect

Comment: Now it's worse than before.